# How can I have group heading for list-group in Bootstrap V4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve something like in the example where I have the name of the state and all the cities below it. I don't know is this the right way to do it in Bootstrap V4? I'm looking for semantically breaking down the large list to smaller, so I can use the html in angular2 app.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="margin:50px">
  <ul class="list-group"><h1>Alabama</h1>
    <li class="list-group-item">Alexander City</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Andalusia</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Anniston</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Athens</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Atmore</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-group"><h1>Alaska</h1>
    <li class="list-group-item">Ajo</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Avondale</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Bisbee</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Casa Grande</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Chandler</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me you are doing just fine.

Another way of achieving it is using cards. for horzontal alignment purposes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="margin:50px">
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-block"><h1 class="card-title">Alabama</h1>
     <p class="card-text">Alexander City</p>
     <p class="card-text">Andalusia</p>
     <p class="card-text">Anniston</p>
     <p class="card-text">Athens</p>
     <p class="card-text">Atmore</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-block"><h1 class="card-title">Alaska</h1>
     <p class="card-text">Ajo</p>
     <p class="card-text">Avondale</p>
     <p class="card-text">Bisbee</p>
     <p class="card-text">Casa Grande</p>
     <p class="card-text">Chandler</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if you want display one at a time you can use accordions.

[link to achieve collapse](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/)